# Validation error for TruCustomApp from trulens_eval - Input should be an instance of Queue [type=is_instance_of, input_value=<queue.Queue object ...>

Tags: python

When runnin the following code: trying to learn from [this post](https://thetechbuffet.substack.com/p/evaluate-llms-with-trulens?utm_source=profile&utm_medium=reader2)

```py
    from trulens_eval import TruCustomApp
    
    tru_rag = TruCustomApp(
        rag,
        app_id="RAG-einstein:v1",
        feedbacks=[
            f_groundedness,
            f_qa_relevance,
            f_context_relevance,
        ],
    )
```

I get the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
    Input In [22], in <module>
          1 from trulens_eval import TruCustomApp
    ----> 3 tru_rag = TruCustomApp(
          4     rag,
          5     app_id="RAG-einstein:v1",
          6     feedbacks=[
          7         f_groundedness,
          8         f_qa_relevance,
          9         f_context_relevance,
         10     ],
         11 )
    
    
    ValidationError: 1 validation error for TruCustomApp records_with_pending_feedback_results 
    Input should be an instance of Queue [type=is_instance_of, input_value=<queue.Queue object at 0x000001310D6CDF40>, input_type=Queue]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/is_instance_of
```

I have tried several variations of the trulens_eval package which bring other problems

current `trulens_eval.__version__` is `'0.23.0'`
Using python3.8

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, a fresh install in a clean environment solved for me. I think it happens due to a clash with other packages.